# What is an efficient Entity Framework query to check if users are friends?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

There is a table called `UserFriends` that holds records for users' friendships.
For each friendship, there is just **one** record,

```
User1ID  User2ID IsConfirmed
1        2       true
```

which is equal in terms of business logic to

```
User1ID  User2ID IsConfirmed
2        1       true
```

but *both* can't happen for one pair.

**What is the most efficient** (yet readable and not involving plain SQL) **[Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) query to determine if user A is a friend of user B, considering we don't know which of them is in first or second column?**

My attempt is plain and obvious:

```
public bool AreFriends (int user1Id, int user2Id)
{
    return MyObjectContext.UserFriends
        .Any (uf => uf.IsConfirmed && (
                    (uf.UserID == user1Id && uf.FriendUserID == user2Id)
                    || (uf.UserID == user2Id && uf.FriendUserID == user1Id)
        ));
}
```

Is there a better way than `||` here?

Comment: if User1ID and User2ID columns both are primary key columns this query cause Index scan and is so efficient. Did you see Execution plan of this query?

Comment: @Nima: No I didn't. So, does having them both as keys make the query efficient? I'm not really a database guy and appreciate input like this. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it, and mark it as correct if nothing else turns up?

Comment: @gaearon - No they aren't 'both as keys' they are the key, when you create your primary key / clustered index on the table it should be across both User1ID and UserID2.

Comment: @Phill: yes, I meant this. They *are* primary key.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me... Its so simple, there is not much room for optimizations.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere `OR`s are ineffective and must be avoided. Since they seem to be OK with a composite key, I'll mark @Nima's answer as correct. Thanks everyone for your contributions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if the User1ID and User2ID columns both are primary key columns this query cause an index seek and is so efficient. Tuning of a query when it is critical, without analysing the execution plan, is inefficient. For important queries, I suggest you use SQL Server (or any DBMS) to write and analyse your queries and then convert these queries to LINQ queries. It is not hard.